# What are the proper domains of the position and squared angular momentum operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, angular-momentum, operators, mathematics

I am looking at the position operator on a compact set $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and the squared angular momentum operator (so essentially the Laplace-Beltrami operator where I just look at the angular parts so this operator acts on $\mathbb{S}^2$). My question is: What are the canonical domains that we adjust to these two operators?

Comment: On $L^2(K)$, multiplication by $x_j$ is a bounded operator I suspect...the squared angular momentum has a complete set of eigenfunctions in the spherical harmonics, but I don't know its precise domain of self-adjointness. A regular domain such as $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{S}^2)$ should be a domain of essential self-adjointness (but I'm not sure).

Comment: yes, at least for $K \subset \mathbb{R}$ we could take the $x \in K$ with maximum absolute value and then this defines our constant for $||xf||_2 \le C ||f||_2$, so you should be correct about the boundedness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$D(\hat{X}_i):= \left\{ \psi \in L^2(K, d^nx)\:\left|\: \int_K x_i^2|\psi(x)|^2 d^nx< \right.+\infty \right\} = L^2(K, d^nx)$$
where the last identity holds true if $K$ is bounded (in particular compact) because $x_i^2$ is bounded as well thereon (in this case the operator is bounded, too).
Moreover
$$D(\hat{J}^2):= \left\{\psi \in L^2(\mathbb S^2, d\Omega)\:\left|\: \sum_{\ell=0\:, -\ell \leq m \leq \ell}^{+\infty} \ell^4 \left| \int_{\mathbb S^2}\psi(s)^*  Y^{\ell}_m(s)\:d\Omega(s) \right|^2<+\infty\right.\right\}$$
With these domains they are automatically self adjoint (not only essentially self-adjoint). If restricting the domain to $C^\infty(\mathbb S^2)$, $\hat{J}^2$ turns out to be essentially self-adjoint, due to a well known theorem by Nelson,  since it is symmetric (with dense domain) and admits a set of analytic vectors (the $Y^\ell_m$s)  whose span is dense in the whole Hilbert space.